# Creating a user friendly interface using an if statement in Java

Tags: java

I don't wish to leave a user stranded by returning nothing.  Normally I can rectify this problem using a simple if else statement but since it's nested inside a for loop I don't get very good result.  Below is my code for returning students attached to a module:

```
System.out.print("Search for a student: ");
                    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String searchStudent = scan.nextLine().trim();

                    for (Student student : students) {
                        if (searchStudent.equalsIgnoreCase(student.getName())) {
                            Iterator it = modules.iterator();
                            Boolean found = false;
                            while (it.hasNext() && !found) {
                                Module module = (Module) it.next();
                                if (module.getStudents().contains(student)) {
                                    System.out.printf("%s ", module.getName());
                                    found = true;
                                }

                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry. " + searchStudent + " does not exist in the database");
                        }
                    }
```

The output:

```
Search for a student: jane
UFCE3 UFCE1 Sorry. jane does not exist in the database
Sorry. jane does not exist in the database
Sorry. jane does not exist in the database
Sorry. jane does not exist in the database
```

Clearly in this example, Jane does exist in the database and she is enrolled on UFCE3 and UFCE1.

Since the if statement is nested inside the for loop I wouldn't expect anything less than getting an inaccurate output as the for loop will continue to loop until all elements in the student array have been passed.  Any advice?

Comment: Try using methods and returning things instead of just printing to the console. This lets you have much greater control over your programs' flow.

Comment: Could you include declaration of students`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a simple sentinel value (boolean flag) to your while statement.  You start the value off as false, and then change it to true when a record is found.

```
Boolean found = false;
 while (it.hasNext() && !found) {
                 Module module = (Module) it.next();
                 if (module.getStudents().contains(student)) {
                            System.out.printf("%s ", module.getName());
                            found = true;
                  }
```

Or you could use a "break" statement to terminate the loop.

```
 while (it.hasNext() ) {
                 Module module = (Module) it.next();
                 if (module.getStudents().contains(student)) {
                            System.out.printf("%s ", module.getName());
                            break;
                  }
```

Comment: @ Boundless Your first option looks like it should work but I'm still returning the same results as before.  I've edited the post to show these changes.

Comment: @MikeGittins Make sure to add the check to your second print statement too: else if(!found){
                            System.out.println("Sorry. " + searchStudent + " does not exist in the database");

Answer (score 1):

extract your for loop into a method, returning the modules you are interested in.

then call that method. check if you get any useful result and print it or print your excuse otherwise.

This is known as seperation of concerns. An entity should do exactly one thig. your for loop does at least three:

- searching for students
- searching for modules
- printing results